# group by in active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one instance variable with two records.

```
           id   item_with_detail_id  quantity

           100       205                3


           101       205                5
```

Now, i want the result as follows using Active record group_by .

```
           100       205                8
```

i tried with

```
@bill_details=@bill_details.group_by{|bd| bd.item_with_detail_id}.values.map(&:first)
```

but its not working. Please help me to achieve the result.

Comment: If i get it right your question is: You want to find the sum of quantity ordered for each item_with_detail_id.

Comment: yes. but using the same above group_by which i have mentioned.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: I don't know whether it's a good question or not. But i don't know how to achieve the desired result. Thats why i was posted the question.

Comment: Cannot see "what is not working" without trying out the same example ourselves. For e.g. What is the specific error you are getting? What is the specific result you are expecting?

Comment: Check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by and http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month?view=asciicast Hope it helps!

Comment: It's ruby 1.9 and rails 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem. As follows

In the controller =>

```
@bill_details = @bill_details.group_by{|bd| bd.item_with_detail_id}.values
```

it will give the following result

```
 #[[#<BillDetail id: 100, item_with_detail_id: 205, quantity: 3, #<BillDetail id:101, item_with_detail_id: 205, quantity: 5]]
```

And in the view page:

```
<% for bd in @bill_details%>
  <%quantity=0%>
  <%for bill_detail in  bd%>
  <%quantity+=bill_detail.quantity%>
  <%end%>
  <%bd=bd.first%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

@bill

```
select("id, item_with_detail_id,SUM(quantity)").group("item_with_group_id")
```

Comment: It's not working Mr. Vairamuthu. It's giving the following error .wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)